# Getting React state of input that has been selected from datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datepicker

Currently working on creating a react component for a form. I am applying a datepicker via a regular javascript file to my inputs which are being rendered in react (jsx).

I am trying to pull the state from the inputs when a date is selected from the datepicker. Unfortunately react is not picking up the value. I know it is probably something to do with calling the datepicker from a regular javascript file onto the rendered inputs. Thing is, when I am calling a regular .val on the input once I have selected a date, it gives me the value.

Also should mention, I am using bootstrap-datepicker

Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated :)

*form.js.jsx*

```
var StepOne = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {start: '', end: ''};
  },
startDateChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({start: e.target.value});
  },
  endDateChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({end: e.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="stepOne">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>Starts</label>
            <input id="event-start" type="text" value={this.state.start} onChange={this.startDateChange} />
            <label>Ends</label>
            <input id="event-end" type="text" value={this.state.end} onChange={this.endDateChange} />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  },
}); // end of component
```

*stepone_datepicker.js*

```
$(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
  $('#event-start, #event-end').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      minDate: new Date(),
      startDate: date
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the date-picker control that you use ?

Comment: First of all, I notice that you use `this.state.end` on one end and you set the state to `end_date`. Secondly, I would not mix jquery an react for this. Maybe you can try some react datepicker components available on github. If you really need to use jQuery, use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook of the react component to run your jquery code, not to mess with the react way of rendering.

Comment: @AlexMoldovan is correct. Because of the way React's virtual DOM works, if jQuery modifies the DOM externally, React does not 'know' about it, and conversely as React re-renders jQuery won't know about those updates.  If you want to use jQuery in React, you'll need to use it within React's life cycle methods and should use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` to reference the DOM elements.

Comment: Makes sense. I knew jQuery would be effecting the DOM differently but didn't think it would effect getting the actual value from the input. Looks like i'm finally just going to get Browserify running and use an actual react datepicker. Thanks for helping me understand this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the `stepone_datepicker.js` file is probably executing before your React component has rendered into the DOM.

Using `id` to reference a DOM node inside a React component is *very rarely* a good idea and generally ends up as confusing spaghetti code.

React gives us a way to get hold of the DOM nodes with it's `refs` mechanism.

First, move the date picker code into a new method in your component.

```
 makeDatePicker: function(element) {
   var date = new Date();
   date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);

   $(element).datepicker({
     autoclose: true,
     minDate: new Date(),
     startDate: date
   });
 }
```

Now we can add the `ref` attribute to each input and use this new method as the callback.

```
<label>Starts</label>
<input ref={this.makeDatePicker} type="text" value={this.state.start} onChange={this.startDateChange} />
<label>Ends</label>
<input ref={this.makeDatePicker} type="text" value={this.state.end} onChange={this.endDateChange} />
```

When the element is ready, React will call `makeDatePicker` and pass the DOM node as the first argument.

After that, you can intercept the DOM node and apply the jQuery plugin.

This way you could even render multiple instances of the `StepOne` component and not have to worry about collisions between `id` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the correct way to do it maybe better to use [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker)

But you can do this to trigger `onChange` event manually

```
$(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
  $('#event-start, #event-end').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      minDate: new Date(),
      startDate: date,
      onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
       var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
       this.dispatchEvent(event);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and maybe better to use `react-dom` to get the DOM node anyway the code that i post with the minimum changes

Comment: Thanks for the note. Just going to get browserify into my application then use an actual react datepicker. Seem's the easiest way to get this working so i'm not effecting the DOM with jquery.